# How to submit newly sorted list of elements, with the library SortableJS

Tags: javascript, sortablejs

I am using the JS library SortableJS and trying to send the newly sorted array on submit.

The JS:

```
var originalArray;
var sortable = Sortable.create(selection, {
  handle: '.bars-move',
  animation: 150,
});

var modalForm = document.getElementById("modalForm");
  if (modalForm  !== null ){
    modalForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      var formData = new FormData(modalForm);
      e.preventDefault();
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open(modalForm.method, modalForm.action, true);
      var cookies = parse_cookies();
      request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', cookies['csrftoken']);
      request.onload = function() {
        /// send the new Array here
      };
      request.send(formData);
    });
  };
```

Any tips welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is simply to submit the sortable array on submit :

```
var sortable = Sortable.create(selection, {
    handle: '.bars-move',
    animation: 150,
  });
```

and

```
var modalForm = document.getElementById("modalForm");
if (modalForm  !== null ){
    modalForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      var formData = new FormData(modalForm);
      e.preventDefault();
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open(modalForm.method, modalForm.action, true);
      var cookies = parse_cookies();
      request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', cookies['csrftoken']);
      formData.append('sortableArray', sortable.toArray());
      request.send(formData);
    });
};
```